# calling PHP script- getting the script as an output

Tags: php

I wrote a simple PHP script to connect to a SQL database. I ran `chmod +x script.php`. The problem is that when I call the script (`./script.php`) the output is the script itself (the whole script written as an output). Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Short tags are probably disabled. Replace `<?` with `<?php`

Answer (score 1):

As @vidarlo suggests, the short tags directive in the PHP configuration file is disabled.
If you'd like to use the short tags syntax, you'll have to enable it.
Change your php.ini file accordingly:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

And restart apache. Assuming you're using some kind of Debian-based system and apache2, execute the following command (or similar, depending on your system):

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Note: If you don't know where your php.ini configuration file is, just run the following in the terminal:

```
php --ini
```

Comment: It appears he is not using apache2 (or any web server). Anyway, I'd say don't enable short tags; change tags to the long form in the script. [Short tags](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) are discouraged, and makes scripts less portable. There's no reason to use them.

Comment: Well, we use short tags in all of our projects, but only in the views. In my opinion, it improves the readability.

Comment: I don't see how a tag that is not repeated trough code improves readability. I typically see it on the first line of the file... Anyway, that is not really the point. Long tags eases portability, as it is supported everywhere, and it is enabled by default. In addition I'd not feel sure that short tags will be around for *that* long either...